# mysqlcluster create table get error 708

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

when I created table in mysqlcluster 7.5.17,I got the error message like

> Got error 708 'No more attribute metadata records (increase MaxNoOfAttributes)' from NDBCLUSTER

so I used ndb_config -q MaxNoOfAttributes got the number for MaxNoOfAttributes was 40960,

I select columns from information_schema get number is 28777

```
select count(*) from information_schema.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('mysql','information_schema','ndbinfo','performance_schema','sys');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    28777 |
+----------+
```

I want to know the MaxNoOfAttributes params where is limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can check more information from this [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxnoofattributes). I will quote relevant paragraph for your case:

> The default value is 1000, with the minimum possible value being 32. The maximum is 4294967039. Each attribute consumes around 200 bytes of storage per node due to the fact that all metadata is fully replicated on the servers.

Need to take caution, this parameter will affect when doing ALTER TABLE by using 3 times number of attributes in that table.

> During the execution of ALTER TABLE on a Cluster table, 3 times the number of attributes as in the original table are used.

Therefore it is necessary to evaluate your table and find the `greatest number of attribute`, multiply it with 6 to be used as this parameter's value.